# Express.js/Nginx hidden rewrite rule?

Tags: php, node.js, express, nginx, passport.js

So I am running an Express.js/Passport.js web server with Nginx on CentOS 7.

Here's the problem: I cannot display any endpoint that starts with `w`.  Trying to do so results in a `Cannot GET /wiki/Main_Page` message.  However, changing that same route from e.g. `/welcome` to `/selcome` works just fine.

Most likely culprit:

I installed Mediawiki but removed it not long after.  IIRC there was some kind of setting that prettied up URLs that starting with `/w` after the domain.  So I'm guessing a rewrite rule is persisting... just have no idea where.

Here are my config files:

`/srv/node/example.com/app/routes/auth.js`

```
module.exports = function(app, passport) {

    //Changing the URLs below from welcome to selcome works fine
    app.get('/activate', passport.authenticate('user-activate-account', {
        successRedirect: '/welcome',
        failureRedirect: '/404',
        failureFlash: true
    }));

    ...

    app.get('/welcome', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
        res.render('inside', { 
            page_title: 'Welcome!',
            inc_style: true,
            style_sheet: 'style/dashboard.css',
            portal: function() {
                 return 'welcome';
               }
        });
    });
};
```

`/etc/nginx.conf`

```
user        nginx nginx;
error_log   /var/log/nginx/error.log info;  # [ debug | info | notice | warn | error | crit ]

events {
    worker_connections   1024;
}

http {
    include     mime.types;
    include     /etc/nginx/sites_enabled/.conf;   //Really *.conf but more readable this way
    include     /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;

    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;

    # Compression - requires gzip and gzip static modules.
    gzip on;
    gzip_static on;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_min_length 700;

    # Compression levels over 6 do not give an appreciable improvement
    # in compression ratio, but take more resources.
    gzip_comp_level 6;

    # IE 6 and lower do not support gzip with Vary correctly.
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    # Before nginx 0.7.63:
    #gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.";

    # Redirect http traffic to https
    server {
        listen      80 default_server;
        server_name _;

        return      301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    # Catch-all server for requests to invalid hosts.
    # Also catches vulnerability scanners probing IP addresses.
    server {
            listen      443 ssl;
        server_name bogus;
        root        /var/empty;

        return      444;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
        }

    # If running php as fastcgi, specify php upstream.
    upstream php {
        server      unix:/var/run/php7.2-fpm.socket;
    }
}
```

`/etc/nginx/sites_available/example.com.conf`

```
#sub.example.com
server {
    ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;    # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;      # managed by Certbot

    listen          443 ssl;
    server_name     sub.example.com;

    access_log      /var/log/nginx/sub.example.com.access.log;
    error_log       /var/log/nginx/sub.example.com.error.log;

    location /something\.js {
        alias       /var/www/html/example.com/sub.example.com/design/;

        location ~* \.(gif|jpe?g|png|svg|webm)$ {
            try_files   $uri =404;
            expires     30d;
        }
    }

    location / {
            proxy_pass          http://localhost:3847;
            proxy_http_version  1.1;
            proxy_set_header    Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header    Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header    Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass  $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

So far I have

- Purged Nginx config files, and every config file in the include tree, of any legacy rules.
- Cleared Nginx cache
- My node.js project folder does not even contain the string `wiki` anywhere except for NPM links in the `node_modules` folder.
- All the PHP files in /etc, /etc/php.d, /etc/php-fpm.d do not contain the string `wiki`
- Deleted mediawiki folder
- Restarted nginx
- Restarted php-fpm
- Restarted entire machine

I'm genuinely baffled at where this problem could be.  Any ideas?

Comment: whats in `sites_enabled` folder? check there for mediawiki one, or a borked default

Comment: `sites_enabled` has symlinks to 2 `.conf` files, both located in sister folder `sites_available`.  All `sites_available` has is 2 configs for 2 domains: `example.com.conf` (relevant portion shown above) and `example2.com.conf`
As for default folder/file, I don't have one.  Like I said, its utterly mystifying :-/

Comment: run `nginx -T` it might yield where its set

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was the browser.  Despite clearing history multiple times and using incognito mode, nothing changed.  But using another browser worked flawlessly.  I feel like an idiot, but at least I can finally put this rage-inducing mystery behind me.

Was using: Firefox (I guess private mode isn't enough)
Chrome showed it was a browser error.